# How to remove a polymorphic relation in Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I have a model like this:

```
<?php

class Post extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];


    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Upload', 'imageable');
    }

    public function attachments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Upload', 'attachable');
    }

}
```

and my `morphMany` table's schema is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `uploads` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`raw_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`size` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`downloads` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`imageable_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`imageable_type` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`attachable_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`attachable_type` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `uploads_user_id_index` (`user_id`),
CONSTRAINT `uploads_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

now I need to remove one row of this table, I tried `$posts->photos()->delete();` but it removed all rows associated to this `Post`.

Could someone help me?

Comment: By what do you want to remove the row? by id?

Comment: yes, sorry for this missing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`$posts->photos()` is the relationship query to return all of the photos for a post. If you call `delete()` on that, it will delete all of those records. If you only want to delete a specific record, you need to make sure you only call delete on the one you want to delete. For example:

```
$posts->photos()->where('id', '=', 1)->delete();
```

Comment: Seems you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512956/how-can-i-add-delete-and-get-a-favorite-from-product-with-polymorphic-relations

Answer (score 9):

to reomove from pivot table in many to many polymorphic relation just use detach:

```
$posts->photos($photoModel)->detach();
```

Comment: Actually, this is the way to go and answers the question. This should be upvoted and accepted but it seems to me neither OP nor commentors even understand what they're dealing with here.

Comment: Be careful - this removes all of the pivotal entries (at least in Laravel 5.2; if it changed afterwards I don't know).

Comment: @JuliusBlatt No, it doesn't answer the question. The relationships defined by the OP are `morphMany`, not `morphToMany`. These are not a many-to-many polymorphic relationships. This code would throw an error because `detach()` does not exist on `morphMany` relationships.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship isn't even needed for this. Just use the Upload model directly:

```
Upload::find($id)->delete();
```

Or even shorter:

```
Upload::destroy($id);
```

Comment: It's polymorphic, the photo ID may exist multiple times. You're approach could delete unintended rows.

Comment: ...i take it back...using your approach, he still has to find the proper row using photo id and user id. Point being, id's may exist multiple times since it is polymorphic.

Comment: @lukasgeiter Seems you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512956/how-can-i-add-delete-and-get-a-favorite-from-product-with-polymorphic-relations